# Hibernate ManyToOne cascade on Add but not on Delete

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a self referential table and in my object model objects only know their parent, but not their children.

I want parent nodes to be created when children are created. But I do not want them deleted when children are deleted. CascadeType.ALL persists, but also deletes as expected. CascadeType.PERSIST, doesn't delete, but also fails to persist.

Is this possible or am I over looking something? Do I have to manually trace up the tree persisting as I go?

The hibernate annotations:

```
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
@Table(name = "NODE")
public class Node implements Cloneable
{   
    @Id
    @Column(name = "KEY")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "NodeSeq", sequenceName = "NODE_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="NodeSeq")
    private long key;

    @ManyToOne (cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinColumn(name="parentkey",referencedColumnName="key")
    private Node parent;

...
}
```

I am using javax.persistance annotations and hibernate 4.3.7

**Update on solution**
Along with using javax.persistence CascadeType, I was using hibernate session.save and saveOrUpdate. This is a buggy solution to be avoided. See [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/)

Comment: If you use session.persist(node) to persist a Node, you will need to add CascadeType.PERSIST to your annotation to persist the Parent with it. If you use session.saveOrUpdate(node), you need to add CascadeType.Save_Update ... and so on.

Comment: By default, there is no cascade, which means if you don't need cascade on delete, it is the default behaviour. If you need to cascade when delete, you add CascadeType.DELETE (or CascadeType.REMOVE if you use session.remove(node))

Comment: @bill-bilal  I have been using session.save and saveOrUpdate to persist. CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE looks to be a hibernate annotation, while I am using javax.persistance annotations. Switching to session.persist did not persist the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use session.saveOrUpdate(node) you can use the hibernate annotation @Cascade :

```
@ManyToOne
@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
@JoinColumn(name="parentkey",referencedColumnName="key")
private Node parent;
```

Comment: I would say should/must use hibernate annotation @Cascade with  session.saveOrUpdate(node)